# RDL file - Reporting Services showing HTML in design view

Tags: reporting-services

for some reason the RDL file
RDL file - Reporting Services showing HTML in design view
in Visual studio

any clues as to why

only thing i can think of it is that it makes use of Dundas Charts and i dont have that installed. Will i need that????

Answer (score 2):

VS2008 will attempt to display an error message as HTML if the RDL has an error (for instance, a unrecognized tag), however the HTML doesn't render properly, resulting in the design view showing plain HTML.

If you're using custom components which aren't installed, it probably thinks there's an error in the RDL.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by copying the html over to a txt document, renaming it, then editing the lines refered to in the html in the rdl file manually. the rdl file contains XML in a readable format, easily edited. In my case the cause of error was a Boolean parameter with illegal "Available Values"

Comment: This solved my problem, the HTML given by BI Studio isn't rendered properly but in there tells you the line where the problem is located.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when i tried to open the RDL in BIDS - 2005(Visual Studio). But the RDL was originally built in BIDS - 2008.

When i tried to open the RDL in BIDS -2008 it worked fine.

Arvind

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I had a similar issue and was able to solve it.  I'm using 2008 and out of nowhere an RDL that was previously opening fine was now opening with error HTML.  I haven't seen anything about this elsewhere, even though I'm sure there's got to be something.  But it is somewhat of a unique combination of events.

I've got a Boolean type parameter with available values set to "On" and "Off" for "True" and "False".  What happened is even though I've set these previously, I opened the parameter properties, changed nothing, then clicked "Cancel", which under normal circumstances you'd believe nothing was changed.  But for some reason, the XML changes from:

```
<ValidValues>
    <ParameterValues>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Value>True</Value>
        <Label>On</Label>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Value>False</Value>
        <Label>Off</Label>
      </ParameterValue>
    </ParameterValues>
  </ValidValues>
```

to:

```
<ValidValues>
    <ParameterValues>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Value DataType="Boolean">True</Value>
        <Label>On</Label>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Value DataType="Boolean">False</Value>
        <Label>Off</Label>
      </ParameterValue>
    </ParameterValues>
  </ValidValues>
```

This change happened unbeknownst to me, I saved and closed the file.  Upon re-opening the file, the viewer apparently breaks on the DataType="Boolean", resulting in the error HTML.  Hope this helps someone.  Why "Cancel" would ever change anything, though, is beyond me.